# Shouldn't FROM come before SELECT in Sql?

Tags: sql, select

This is something that has always bothered me. Wouldnt it make more sense to have the FROM clause come before the SELECT? Whenever Im writing sql, especially with joins, I always figure out the FROM clause first and then write the SELECT.

Plus, putting the FROM first would allow for better intellisense inside the editor.

Does anyone know what the reasoning was to have SELECT come first? Am I only one who is bothered by this?

Comment: Which one of these sounds more natural to you: select fruit from basket where basket contains oranges or from basket select fruit where basket contains apples? The latter would be easier for intellisense but the former easier for us mere humans, especially if we wouldn't happen to be programmers.

Comment: The "better intellisense" was the main reason the LINQ team at Microsoft changed the order of the keywords - other than that: I guess you can argue pro and con for both approaches, and unless you want to write your own database, the argument is pretty moot...

Comment: @AleksiYrttiaho If we wouldn't happen to be programmers then we wouldn't be writing SQLs, right? I think SQL should be designed for not mere humans but programmers who will use it.

Comment: @SnowBlind SQL is a funny language that is also used by people who are not quite programmers. There's a lot of people who've learned some of the basics and use SQL with Access or similar software and there's those who are maintaining or using data with some recipe-like SQL because it is more cost-effective to teach them a bit of SQL instead of creating a sufficiently powerful and easy to use UI for only a few users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is strange and counterintuitive. Hugh Darwen theorises about how this state of affairs came about:

> Do you take SELECT-FROM-WHERE for
>   granted, or do you, like me, find it
>   rather curious that the System R team
>   should have spurned the normal way of
>   writing expressions of arbitrary
>   complexity in favour of something
>   utterly idiosyncratic and, one might
>   say, rather dictatorial...?
>
> The fact is that in the 1960s various
>   scripting languages (as we tend to
>   call such things these days) had come
>   about for the purposes of report
>   generation, especially ad hoc report
>   generation.  We had one such language
>   in the prerelational DBMS called
>   Terminal Business System (TBS) that I
>   worked on for IBM from 1969-77.  Our
>   language required the user to specify
>   the required report in a series of
>   steps that had to be given *in the
>   prescribed order*...
>
> A somewhat similar but much more
>   sophisticated report generator was
>   later developed by IBM in the US, as
>   part of a product called (prosaically,
>   as was IBM's style in those days)
>   Generalized Information System
>   (GIS)... when I first looked at SQL,
>   my immediate reaction was  "Oh no! 
>   Son of GIS?  Please not that!"  I
>   might have been quite wrong about
>   this.  The similarity I perceived
>   might have been illusory and even if
>   it was not, I have no firm evidence
>   that anybody in the System R team was
>   familiar with GIS.  The fact remains
>   that the general style of a fixed
>   order of actions was the order of the
>   day at the time.  I postulate that
>   SQL's SELECT-FROM-WHERE arose out of
>   this fashion.

From [`HAVING` a Blunderful Time](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HAVING-A-Blunderful-Time.html)

Answer (score 6):

The syntax was to resemble English, according to an [oral history interview with Donald D. Chamberlin](https://hdl.handle.net/11299/107215):

> It was our first attempt to base the language exclusively on
> English keywords so that you could read a query from an intuitive understanding of the English words. A query might say something like, ‘Select salary from employee where manager equals John Smith.’ From the English words like ‘select,’ ‘from’ and ‘where’, you can get a pretty good idea for what the query is about.

Comment: +1 Nice [Donald D. Chamberlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_D._Chamberlin) interview.